# how to get the startgazer count for a github repo without having to copy the button

Tags: reactjs, github, github-api

I am trying to add the stargazers count from my repo to my own button that I styled for a static react site (using Docusaurus - not sure if that matters, though :)

Not sure how to get just the count onto my button without needing to go to buttons.github.io, choose their pre-styled button and downloading the iframe.

I found there is an api src that is available but it's not working:

src="https://api.github.com/repos/{name}/{reponame}?page=$i&type=star&count=true&size=large"

Would be really appreciative if there is someone who tried the same and might have a solution.

Comment: Is your repo private? Because than this api will not work. Your repo needs to be public. Do you also not get anything in your browser? I am also not sure if you want to place this URL in the src.

Comment: Hi @mathijng, thanks very much for your response. It's a public repo. But now that you mention not to place this URL in the src, I'm thinking maybe that's why it won't work directly inside of a button. 

Do you think that using the GH button in an iFrame is the only option?